# Pentaho kettle conveting month numeric value to month name

Tags: pentaho, olap, kettle

I am facing an issue related to olap and kettle. Thing is I am using pentaho DI(kettle) to export data from my database to olap star schema(facts & dimensions). Now when it comes to timestamp I am able to retreive months,years and days from aw timestamp using calculator in kettle . Now What I need is to convert month numeric value to its coresponding month name (like replace 1 with JAN and so on). How this can be acheived with kettle . Please suggest me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PDI/Kettle, I've found it tricky to set the value of one field based on the value of another field that is a different data type. A `JavaScript` or `Formula` step will do it, but in this case I think I'd use a `Stream Lookup` because your lookup values are few and fixed.

Use a `Data Grid` step with an Integer column for the month number (1, 2, 3 ...) and a string column with the month name (JAN, FEB, MAR ...). Use this step as the 'Lookup step' in your `Stream Lookup`. Then just retrieve the month name into your data flow. This should be pretty fast, which is good if you're working with typical data warehouse volumes.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian said you can also use the Modified JavaScript step to perform the conversion. Here is how you can do it with that:

```
var month_names=new Array();
month_names[1]="Jan";
month_names[2]="Feb";
month_names[3]="Mar";
month_names[4]="Apr";
month_names[5]="May";
month_names[6]="Jun";
month_names[7]="Jul";
month_names[8]="Aug";
month_names[9]="Sep";
month_names[10]="Oct";
month_names[11]="Nov";
month_names[12]="Dec";
var month_short = month_names[month_num];
```